# Fractional Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, fractional-calculus

I am facing the following problem.
If u[x_,t_]=t+y[t]x,
Then,
D[u[x,t],t]
Gives us
1+xy'[t].
But if I use the command for Fractional Derivative like
FractionalD [u[x,t],{t,a}], then Mathematica print as it is. But i want the relationship like 1+xy'[t] but in Fractional Derivative notation. Is there any possibility?

All the best,
Ali.

Comment: So what exactly do you expect as output from your fractional derivative?

Comment: Do you mean the difference in the behavior of `D[t + y[t]* x,t]`and  `FractionalD[t + y[t]* x,{t,3/2}]`?

Comment: No,  it's answer should be like
FractionalD [t]+x* D^{\alpha}x[t]. I mean for unknown functions, it should be fractional derivative notation as for the ordinary derivative.